# Download stopping at 800KB

Tags: google-chrome, download

I have a problem with downloading in chrome browser, whenever I try to download anything (jpg mp3 mp4 exe) the download hangs around 800 KB for at least 30 minutes or so and continues to download. so i downloaded free download manager Uget, but same problem in that too. What would be the cause..?

Comment: This happens only in google chrome (did you test firefox and IE)? What version of chrome? What extensions do you have installed? Any intrusive software installed (AV, anti-malware, etc)?

Comment: Seeing it look like it pauses for a few seconds is one thing, waiting 30min for it to start again, no way :-)  I would want to see my Net I/O long before waiting that long.  What is the method of connection?  What is the OS?  What is the hardware (specially the network interface)? What is the router thing?  What type of ISP are you connected to?